# Outputting json into a helm environment variable

Tags: json, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to output `json` into an envvar in a `kubernetes` deployment with `helm`, for consumption in a `pydantic` settings module.

I have tried the following, which *looks* great with `--dry-run` and `--debug`:

```
containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    env:
      - name: NODE_HOSTS
        value: {{ .Values.stuff.nodeHosts | toJson }}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field EnvVar.spec.template.spec.containers.env.value of type string
```

When I try to actually apply it to a `kubernetes` 1.26 cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by simply single-quoting the result in the pipeline:

```
containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    env:
      - name: NODE_HOSTS
        value: {{ .Values.stuff.nodeHosts | toJson | squote }}
```